# Проверить условие, хранимое в файле или переменной типа String

Tags: android, java

Появилась необходимость хранить условия вида *B>0 && C<2* в текстовом файле.
Затем эти условия программа должна проверить на валидность и выполнить определённую операцию.
Сам текст могу записать в переменную типа *String*. А как проверить условие на валидность?

```
String s = "B>0 && C<2";
if(*значение s*)
    a = 0;
else
    a = 1;
```

Comment: парсер надо писать, анализировать каждый символ и принимать решения относительно его

Comment: Анализировать придётся массивы, количество которых не постоянно. В js это просто делается. А в java это проблематично из-за компиляции в байт-код как я понимаю. Но неужели нет простого способа это обойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы свел задачу к наиболее общему виду. Допустим, нам надо анализировать три переменные. Условие B > 0 эквивалентно принадлежности множеству (0; +oo). Условие C < 2 эквивалентно (-oo; 2). Относительно A условий нет, что эквивалентно принадлежности множеству (-oo; +oo). Запишем эти условия как шесть чисел: -2000000000 +2000000000 0 2000000000 -2000000000 2

Comment: Как я понял, Вы предлагаете условие (A && B>0 && C<2) представить в виде числового диапазона (-2000000000 +2000000000 0 2000000000 -2000000000 2). Где каждой переменной указывается допустимый интервал из 2 чисел. Мне остаётся такую строчку через split перевести в массив и проверить на валидацию.
Так как в android прикрутить скриптинг у меня не получилось, то похоже, что этот ответ будет лучше. Благодарю.

Comment: @arkada38: Да, все так. Я не стал объяснять дальше тривиальные вещи.

Answer (score 2):

Простого способа сделать это на Java нет. Либо вы пишите свой парсер и интерпретатор подобных выражений ([раз](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лексический_анализ), [два](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Синтаксический_анализ), [три](http://www.google.by/search?q=написание+интерпретатора+на+java)), либо прикручиваете готовый парсер (например [Rhino](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino) - движок JavaScript для Java, или [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)), либо пересматриваете архитектуру вашего приложения таким образом, чтобы необходимость в интерпретации произвольных выражений отпала.